# How to use a function as a value in an association?

Tags: syntax, associations, pure-function

I just started learning Mathematica. I was wondering if it is possible to use a function as an value in an association. Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
fas = Association["a" -> 2/5, "fa" -> (# + 1/2) &];
```

And I wish that I could use `fas[["fa"]]` to get access the function `(# + 1/2) &`.

Comment: You can also write `fas["fa"]`.

Comment: If you want to use `Part`, you must write `fas[[2]]`,

Comment: It's a question of precedence. Try `"fa" -> (# + 1/2 &)` with the parentheses around the function, including the `&`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a precedence issue.

`"fa" -> (# + 1/2) &` is interpreted as `( "fa" -> (# + 1/2) ) &`.

Write `"fa" -> ( (# + 1/2) & )` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works!